# Google Map Marker Clusterer "if does not expand" function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a Google map with marker clustering. I have a demo here:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/LxLwZZ?editors=0010

I'd like to create a function on the cluster click event that triggers when the cluster you click does not expand.

Walk through:

1. You click the `4` next to London, the map expands to show those markers
2. You click the `3` and the map expands to show the next markers
3. You click the `2` and the map **still shows `2`** – a function is fired.

I can do something like this:

```
var oldSize = false;

google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {

  var newSize = cluster.getSize();
  var extra = '';
  if(newSize == oldSize){
    alert('this is the same size as it was previously!');
  }
  oldSize = newSize;
  
});
```

But this is **not what I want**, as what happens is...

1. You click the `4` next to London, the map expands to show those markers
2. You click the `3` and the map expands to show the next markers
3. You click the `2` and the map still shows `2`
4. You click the `2` and the map still shows `2` and now the alert fires

Can anyone help me trigger a function a step earlier?

### Further info:

I have a map of items you can visit in certain museums, or other geographic locations. As you click each marker, I load information into the page. Some of the items, however, are in the same museum. The issue I'm having is when the lat and lng is exactly the same for multiple markers, the cluster stays there forever.

This is fine, however in this case I'd like to load the information for all markers in the same location. So I'm trying to create the function to do that when you click on a cluster that doesn't expand. The issue is, that I'm finding it simple to do that the second time you click a cluster that doesn't expand, but not the first time...

Its further complicated by the fact that when you are zoomed out a long way, if you click a cluster I don't want to load all the information for all clusters. I only want to trigger this function when you aren't going to be able to zoom in anymore.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click on the "2" the first time?  The issue is that there are two markers at exactly the same place.  The usual solution to that is the [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/).

Comment: @geocodezip Please see further info in question – the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier looks great – I'll check it out.

Comment: There have been a couple of similar questions posted that I remember passing by.

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Maps InfoWindow on Clusters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533817/google-maps-infowindow-on-clusters)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong because:

1. You click the 4 next to London, the map expands to show those
   markers (4 != false)
2. You click the 3 and the map expands to show the next markers (3 != 4)
3. You click the 2 and the map still shows 2 (2 != 3)
4. You click the 2 and the map still shows 2 and now the alert fires (2 == 2)

You can try to check if all the positions in the cluster markers are equals:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
  var clusterMarkers = cluster.getMarkers();
  var lastPosition;
  if(clusterMarkers.every((currentMarker) => {
    if(!lastPosition || lastPosition.equals(currentMarker.position)) {
        lastPosition = currentMarker.position;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  })) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```