# Detect click on cluster-marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to detect a click on a cluster-marker in Google Maps.

So the code I used is:

```
function clusterMarkers() {
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersArrayFiltered, clusterOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
      console.log('CLUSTERCLICK');
    });
}
```

The "clusterclick" however is never fired. What could be wrong?

What's the correct way to bind a click-event to a cluster-marker?

Comment: What version of `MarkerClusterer` are you using? Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your isssue?  The `clusterclick` works in my answer to the question: [Google Maps InfoWindow on Clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533817/google-maps-infowindow-on-clusters)

Comment: it's 1.0.3 ... as soon as I find time I will try to add an example...

Comment: ok, after analysing the MarkerCluster-script-source, the right code seems to be `google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster.map, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {`

Comment: `markerCluster.map` looks wrong to me, that event is not on the `map`, it should be on the `markerClusterer` (from the example I referenced above: `google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {)

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to the party, but in my case,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(global_marker_cluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster)...
```

had to be changed with 'click' instead of 'clusterclick'
(maybe relevant to the answer, but i use CDN source with : new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm even later to the party but this is the way I achieved this.
You can find more information [here](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/interfaces/MarkerClustererOptions.html#onClusterClick)

```
function clusterMarkers() {

    clusterOptions.onClusterClick = function(event,cluster,map) {
        console.log('clusterclick')
        // if you want to still keep the default behaviour, keep the line below
        map.fitBounds(cluster.bounds);
    }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersArrayFiltered, clusterOptions);
}
```